# Ubuntu Power down

Tags: power-management

I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS and I am having problems shutting down the computer. I trigger a shutdown, the computer says: "reboot: Power down" and pc does not power off.
What problem may I have and what should I do to solve it?

Comment: what happens if you open a terminal and type `sudo poweroff` ? Can you see any messages?

Comment: You may have some part of shutdown hung and waiting for a timeout. Issue your shutdown command and don't touch your system for 30+ minutes. It will eventually shutdown. After the reboot, `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` will tell you .

Comment: if i type sudo poweroff on the monitor received message [265.956676] reboot: Power down and the pc freezes.

Comment: If i type sudo journalctl -b -1 -e: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
Stopped Create System Users.
multipathd.service: Succeeded.
Stopped Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller.
swap.img.swap: Succeeded.
Deactivated swap /swap.img.
Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.

Comment: adguard lvm[4709]:   1 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" unmonitored
lvm2-monitor.service: Succeeded.
Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Reached target Shutdown.
Reached target Final Step.
systemd-poweroff.service: Succeeded.
Finished Power-Off.
Reached target Power-Off.
Shutting down.
adguard systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
adguard systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
adguard systemd-journald[335]: Journal stopped